# How can I unscrew this protected screw?

Tags: screws, security

I think this was used to secure a weapon in the property I bought. It is like a flat drive, but only clockwise. One of four fixing was with a normal screw, which I removed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the entire part? This may help identify the type and maker of the part. Then we can find the installation manual and see if that has removal instructions.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdMTVQxIBHA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are security screws and are designed to not be removed.

Common methods are:

1. Drill the screw head out
2. Cut a new slot
3. Use extractor tools (these are of questionable utility)
4. Grasp the sides of the head (hard, it was designed to resist this kind of removal)
5. Get behind the screw and cut it off. This is a good option if you're going to tear out the wood on the wall anyway.

In your case, could you consider leaving it in place? Even if you do not have the small arms it was originally designed to secure, having a solid, secure mounting point can secure things like valuables, bikes, strongboxes, or safes.

Comment: You beat me to it.  I was writing essentially the same answer.  One way to do #4 is to use a tool like ceramic tile nippers to grab the back of the head and work them behind the head.  You can then use them to turn the screw enough to grab the head with vice grips.  Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_B4iRpBe7U

Comment: BTW, to you "questionable utility" comment on the extractors--Home Depot sells one.  There is a long list of people saying it doesn't work.  The manufacturer's response on each one is to call their tech support; they won't publish any advice.  So darn, if you ain't right.

Comment: I have had luck with a cut off disk on a dremel to make a slot and left handed drill bits. When the drill bit grabs the screw backs out, works great on larger screws bolts.

Comment: Another good way to cut a slot is with an angle grinder and a thin blade.

Comment: Added an image of the entire part. Thanks for the tips, I'll try to make a flat bit slot using a dremel.